# Double-click a word to select it

Tags: android, double-click

Consider the following situation:
I have a text on my screen and I want to double click the words in the text and, for example make this word appear as a toast message.
Does the community have any ideas how to implement this functionality?
I do have some experience developing for android, but not much :(

I would be very thankful for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

you may use GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener. here is the doc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html

for working example following might be helpful

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/